# Javascript get file contents loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have been trying to get a function to reload every second.

I can do this with php get file contents (and meta page reload) but I am also using JS to display time and its not instant at loading so it has a flashing effect.

I have tried this with JS but it is showing nothing.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Vivarium Enviroment Control Centre</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateTime() {
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var hours = currentTime.getHours();
        var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
        var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
        if (minutes < 10){
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }
        if (seconds < 10){
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }
        var v = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " ";
        if(hours > 11){
            v+="PM";
        } else {
            v+="AM"
        }
        setTimeout("updateTime()",1000);
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=v;
    }
updateTime();

$("document").ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#wifi").load('wifiout.php');
    },1000);
});


function changeStatus() {
    var image = document.getElementById('lightStatus');
    if (image.src.match("lightoff")) {
        image.src = "lighton.png";
    } else {
        image.src = "lightoff.png";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="topbar">
    <span id="time"></span>
    <div id="wifi"></div>
    <img id="lightStatus" class="right" onclick="changeStatus()" src="lightoff.png" width="32" height="32">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using jQuery syntax but I don't see it included?

Comment: This is something I've never done before so it is very possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/90/)**

You're missing jQuery plugin declaration, add the following line before your script tag :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

**NOTE :** call the `updateTime()` function inside ready function or you will get the following error :

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Because you're trying to use span `time` when the page not fully loaded yet.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: Q updated to reflect change made.  The file `wifiout.php` only contains an image tag, and its not being displayed on the page.

Comment: Working example here http://acharki.byethost31.com/test.html, check my update the problem was in `updateTime()` call.